# Subtract 1 digit integer

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to write an algorithm program that has a step which involves subtracting a 1 digit integer by 1.

Which means: 3 -> 2, 5 -> 4, 0 -> 9, etc.

My current code is:

```java
int subtractByOne(int val) {
    val = val - 1;
    return (val == -1) ? 9 : val;
}
```

So my point is, is there any operation or formula that will change 0 -> 9, and other cases like usual without an if branch statement?

I'm thinking about bit manipulation but I can barely find it. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a mod:

```
return (val + 9) % 10;
```

Comment: Great. ^^ Thank you for that :) Why I haven't think about it earlier :)

Comment: You will next time :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid modulo, you can do the following:

```
int subtractByOne(int val) {
    val = val - 1;
    return val + ((val >> 31) & 10);
}
```

`val >> 31` will be zero unless `val` is negative, when it is all ones, so the correction term will only be applied when the original `val` was `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
int subtractByOne(int val) {
    return (val - 1) % 10;
}
```

The modulo function should return what you are looking for.

Comment: i just tried that and (-1)%10 in Java actually returns -1

Answer (score 0):

You can use following

```
Math.abs(~val<<3)+1
```

but it has limitations its useful when you want to change to 9 only if you want further you  can change bits.